# Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall post installation script

Tags: 20.04, pxe, curtin

I set up Ubuntu 20.04 with auto-install PXE and everything works. Now I want to run my `post-install.sh` script after installation which does some custom stuff for me like install HP server utility, prepare for git, then checkout code, and run some homebrew application etc.

I did the following to execute that script, but I get errors with a bunch of commands missing paths.  I believe it's because of `/target` environment. How do I run that shell script the normal way without dealing with `/target`?

```
late-commands:
    - wget http://10.70.0.20/post-install.sh -P /target/root/
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- /root/post-install.sh
```

Can I do `chroot /target` and run that script? How do people deal with this issue?

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: I will make an FYI: that's an internal IP address.  10.70.0.20 is within 10.0.0.0/8, so this is likely **specific** to their environment, and NOT something that we can drigger.  It sounds like they are trying to do a post-install configuration *script* and have curtin execute it within their own environment and their PXE environment, making the issue that Nmath stated a non-issue.  Rejecting flag.

Answer (score 0):

you should chmod and run the script after. This should work:

```
late-commands:
- wget http://10.70.0.20/post-install.sh -P /target/root/
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- chmod +x /root/post-install.sh
- curtin in-target --target=/target -- bash /root/post-install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

the target environment cannot see the installer environment. Therefore all data needs to be present in /target which has a similar layout as /

For every post-install line I have one script with the defined environment declared in the header. FYI, each line in late-commands is executed with `sh -c "rest of command"`